# Clean MySQL tables with failed foreign checks

Tags: join, foreign-keys, mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I have a giant mysql sql dump file. But I'm getting error when I try to import it because of foreign key checks. Somehow there is missing data, so I'm importing it with

```
SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and it works, but I'm looking for a solution for missing data.

So is there any automatic way to find and delete relation data with missing entries to get a clean database dump, or I have to go and write manuel SQL for every relation, write query to delete missing values ?

Comment: When you are done cleaning you won't forget about `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` I hope :p

Comment: It is SESSION variable ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate a delete statement like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS check_foreign $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `check_foreign`()
BEGIN
DECLARE finishing INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE vstmt VARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE vtbname VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE vtbnameref VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE vtbcol VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE vtbcolref VARCHAR(50);

DECLARE cr_tables CURSOR FOR select a.table_name, a.referenced_table_name, a.column_name, a.referenced_column_name from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE a where a.table_schema = 'protocol_manager' and a.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME is not null order by a.table_name;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR not found SET finishing = 1;

OPEN cr_tables;

SET vstmt = '';

table_foreign_delete: loop

if finishing = 1 then
    leave table_foreign_delete;
end if;

FETCH cr_tables INTO vtbname, vtbnameref, vtbcol, vtbcolref;

SET vstmt = CONCAT(vstmt, char(10), 'DELETE FROM ', vtbname, ' a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ', vtbnameref, ' b WHERE a.', vtbcol, ' = b.',  vtbcolref, ');');

end loop table_foreign_delete;

select vstmt;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can even do deep search to find a way to execute it dynamicly. For example a temporary table with a trigger. You generate a delete statement, insert it into the temp table, trigger the insert that fires a another (func, proc) to execute the statement generated.

Comment: Well I understand that, I have to clean it by manual :) Thanks for this function.